# borderless wpf window behavior for .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Does anyone know how to have a borderless wpf window in **.Net 3.5**?

Basically I am trying to have the same window as in mahapps metro but in .net 3.5. When I try to use the borderless behavior in the mentioned library, I get a thick dark border around right/bottom side of the window.

I want to avoid **AllowsTransparency** and use hook messages instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `ResizeMove` to `NoResize` or `CanMinimize`. This will remove the border.

> NoResize or CanMinimize gets rid of the nice drop shadow effect and I don't want to loose the resizing (with grip).

In that case you should implement your own shadow (not so hard - just put everything inside one `Border` with desirable margin and set the `DropShadowEffect`). `CanMinimize` will still allow you to resize the window, but you must still [implement your own resizing](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/wpf-custom-window-resizing-101303.aspx).

Comment: `NoResize` or `CanMinimize` gets rid of the nice drop shadow effect and I don't want to loose the resizing (with grip).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the border altogether, you have to set "WindowStyle" to "None" and the "ResizeMode" to "NoResize" or "CanMinimize".